# How does Model.fit() method's shuffle deals with Batches when using a tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, shuffle, tf.data.dataset

I am using tensorflow 2.

When using the `Model.fit()` method with a `tf.data.Dataset`, the argument '`batch_size`' is ignored. Thus to train my model on batches, I have to first change my dataset of samples into a dataset of batches of samples by calling `tf.data.Dataset.batch(batch_size)`.

Then, after reading the documentation, I don't understand clearly how the `.fit()` method will shuffle my dataset at each epoch.

**Since my dataset is a dataset of batches, will it shuffle the batches among each other** (the batches remain unchanged) **? Or will it shuffle all the samples and then regroup them into new batches** (which is the desired behaviour) **?**

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `shuffle` parameter has no effect on the `fit` function when using the `tf.data.Dataset` API.

If we read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) (emphasis is mine) :

> shuffle: Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch) or str (for 'batch'). **This argument is ignored when x is a generator.** 'batch' is a special option for dealing with the limitations of HDF5 data; it shuffles in batch-sized chunks. Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not None.

It's not super clear, but we can have a hint that the shuffle argument will be ignored when using a `tf.data.Dataset`, as it behave like a generator.

To be certain, lets dive in the code. If we look at the code of the [`fit`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L824-L1146) method, you will see that the data is handled by a special class, `DataHandler`. Looking at the code of this class, we see that this is an Adapter class to handle different kind of data. We are interrested in the class that handle tf.data.Dataset, [`DatasetAdapter`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.1/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L678-L752), and we can see that this class does not take into account the `shuffle` parameter :

```py
  def __init__(self,
               x,
               y=None,
               sample_weights=None,
               steps=None,
               **kwargs):
    super(DatasetAdapter, self).__init__(x, y, **kwargs)
    # Note that the dataset instance is immutable, its fine to reuse the user
    # provided dataset.
    self._dataset = x

    # The user-provided steps.
    self._user_steps = steps

    self._validate_args(y, sample_weights, steps)
```

---

If you want to shuffle your dataset, use the [shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) function from the `tf.data.Dataset` API.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. To go further, If I want to shuffle my dataset each epoch during training. Would doing `dataset.shuffle(len_dataset).batch(batch_size)` and `model.fit(num_epochs, ....)` be enough ?    Or do I have have to call, `dataset.shuffle(len_dataset).batch(batch_size).repeat()` and `model.fit(steps_per_epoch=len_dataset//batch_size, ...)`. Or is it equivalent ?

Comment: @Matt I am pretty certain that calling shuffle once should reshuffle the dataset between each epoch. It is something you could verify with a toy example.